# Minecraft PE Server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Me and my friends have a MC PE survival world, and we can only play when I am online (As the game is on my device). I was looking into putting the game onto a raspberry pi4 or an old Windows PC (I would rather use the Pi, its much newer).

My main question is this: **Is it possible to create a server on Raspberry Pi with an existing world?**

My google searches have only turned up things that you cannot import old worlds into, you have to start new. I also want to be able to download the world off the server and play it from the device (And especially take backups). There would be a max of 5-6 players, so nothing extreme.

Thanks in advance.